# What GTK widget is this?

Tags: application-development, gtk

Lately, I've seen the widget below appear in GTK applications. I can't find it in Glade. What is it?

[image]

Comment: It might help if you tell us in which GTK apps you've seen it. Thanks!

Comment: That one is from Totem, but we also see them everywhere in the System Settings, for instance. At least in Precise. Is it possible that it's only a button group with some specific styling?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at the [Totem code](http://git.gnome.org/browse/totem/tree/src/totem-playlist.c#n1685), it looks like a set of [GktButtons inside a GtkToolbar](http://git.gnome.org/browse/totem/tree/data/playlist.ui#n92), with a CSS style applied and using symbolic icons (which are also installed by the theme in Ubuntu) instead of the stock ones.

Here's an example in Python

```
# Assuming builder is an initialized Gtk.Builder object and toolbar exists
# in the .ui definition file and is populated with Gtk.ToolButtons

context = builder.get_object('toolbar').get_style_context()
context.add_class(Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_INLINE_TOOLBAR)
```

More info on GTK+ 3 CSS styles:

- [The GNOME journal: styling GTK with CSS](http://gnomejournal.org/article/107/styling-gtk-with-css)
- [GtkCssProvider documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkCssProvider.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is buttons on ".inline-toolbar"..