# How do I use this Add/remove widget?

Tags: application-development, gtk, quickly, pygtk, glade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What GTK widget is this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108738/what-gtk-widget-is-this)

How do I add this little add/remove GTK widget in Glade Designer 3.12.1?
I don't see it anywhere in the widget bar.

[image]

If it can't be done using the Glade Designer, then what should I add to the Glade file to get it?