# Glade Widget Color

Tags: python, application-development, gtk, glade

I start to get familiar with glade and quickly but one thing I can't figure out. How can I set colors, e.g. background colors or label font colors? Can I do this in Glade or do I have to do it in Python?

Thanks

Stefanie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically for labels, there is an Attributes property in the general tab (about half way down) where you can set formatting options.

You may like to check out this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/108921/50523 on applying styles to widgets, in code.